# WPF binding updates object it's not supposed to

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

So my problem is as follows:

I am passing an object called ***Items*** of class ***MyClass*** into a new instance of ***MyWindow*** in WPF. And I am passing by value, not by reference. Then I bind certain controls (textboxes, comboboxes, etc.) of ***MyWindow*** to the properties of a new field called ***ItemsReplicate*** of ***MyClass*** that belongs to ***MyWindow*** and is made equal to ***Items***. However, when I make changes to any control in ***MyWindow***, ***Items***'s properties get overwritten too for some reason. Is this normal? Or am I missing out on something?

Here's the code description:

```
var passThis = (MyClass)myItem;
MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow(passThis);

public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow (MyClass _item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        innerItem = _item;
        this.DataContext = innerItem ;
    }

    private MyClass innerItem;
}
```

So in the end of this procedure, any changes made via binding affects both **myItem** and **innerItem**

Many thanks.

*PS: Binding mode: Two-way*

Comment: add your code to the question.

Comment: Appologies, I did so. Please check it again.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4347902/1136211

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know that a class instance is always passed by value. I created a deep clone of myClass in order to pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after comment.

Default parameter passing for classes is per reference, even without the "ref" keyword, which only makes changes to the reference of the object itself visible "on the outside".

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();

MyMethod(c);
MyRefMethod(ref c);

public void MyMethod(MyClass innerc)
{
    innerc = new MyClass(); //stays local, c is still its old reference
}

public void MyRefMethod(ref MyClass innerc)
{
    innerc = new MyClass(); //c becomes a new reference to the local innerc
}
```

As in your case: You pass a copy of the reference to MyClass as '_item'. You then store that reference-copy in 'innerItem' as well as in the DataContext. It is still only one Instance of MyClass with multiple reference-copies. Every copy of a reference just points to the same instance of the class.

When you modify the values of your public properties of MyClass with the binding in WPF, the values inside of your original instance of MyClass are getting an update.

In other words: This is normal behavior.

If you really want a deep copy of your Class, [the easiest way is to serialize and desialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects).

Comment: Many thanks for your response! Yet what I have done (please see the edited version of my question with the added codes) is something different.

Comment: That's still the same in the way, that you don't hand over a copy of MyClass but a reference to the same copy. Therefore it is still normal behavior and identical to the MyMethod. 

My "ref"- explanation was just to make another point clear. In both cases you pass a reference, as well as in your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wasn't aware of this. I managed to get around the problem by creating a deep clone of the class instance as you pointed out (shallow copy didn't cut it). Cheers.